# Use phantomjs and casperjs with a nodejs script?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I extracted casperjs and phantomjs in a bins folder.

I want to use casperjs from my nodejs application.

This is my current script:

```
var exec = require('child_process'),
    path = require('path');

// Directory paths where I extracted phantomjs and casperjs.
var phantomjs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'bins', 'phantomjs', 'phantomjs');
var casperjs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'bins', 'casperjs', 'bin', 'casperjs');

// I tried to edit the PATH but it doesn't work.
// process.env.PATH = process.env.PATH + ':' + phantomjs;
// process.env.PATH = process.env.PATH + ':' + casperjs;

// Now launch a casperjs script and get result.
var p = exec.spawn(casperjs, ['test.js']);
p.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

When I run my script, I get an error:

```
Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?
```

Is there a way to use phantomjs and casperjs with exec.spawn()?

**EDIT: I found my problem, I added the wrong paths to the system PATH.**

I added the paths of the files but that's stupid, I must add the path of the directories !

This is the correct code:

```
var exec = require('child_process'),
    path = require('path');

// Directory paths where I extracted phantomjs and casperjs.
var phantomjs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'bins', 'phantomjs');
var casperjs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'bins', 'casperjs', 'bin');

// console.log(process.env.PATH);
process.env.PATH = process.env.PATH + ':' + phantomjs;
process.env.PATH = process.env.PATH + ':' + casperjs;
// console.log(process.env.PATH);

// Now launch a casperjs script and get result.
var p = exec.spawn('casperjs', ['test.js']);
p.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: Did you try to install it from [npm](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-npm) ? with the `-g` flag. You won't have PATH problem like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here with exec (I didn't try with spawn) :

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

exec('casperjs test scriptName.js',function(err,stdout,stderr){
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
});
```